# why the getview method doesn't work?

Tags: listview, getview

i have a custom listview to show my data.
and i have a custome adapter too. 
my question is ((why the getview method doesn't work?)) 
my adapter code is:

```
package ir.mrcoder.triples;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;   
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<job> {

List<job> JobsList=new ArrayList<job>();
private Context context;
TextView JobsName;
TextView JobsTime;
TextView JobsDate;
job TestJob;

public myAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<job> objects) 
{
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.JobsList=objects;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_listview, parent, true);
    JobsName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.JobsName);
    JobsTime=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.JobsTime);
    JobsDate=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.JobsDate);
    job myJob=JobsList.get(position);
    JobsName.setText(myJob.name);
    JobsTime.setText(myJob.timeOfDoing);
    JobsDate.setText(myJob.dateOfDoing);
    return convertView;
}
}
```

and i call the list view and the adapter in this way:

```
  List<job> JobsList=new ArrayList<job>();
    ListView JobShowList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.JobShowList);
    myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.my_listview, JobsList);
    JobShowList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

my question is ((why the getview method doesn't work?))

Comment: i should telling that my data is full but in listview show nothing

Comment: Edit this line `inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_listview, parent, false)`.